# Showing value labels in axes 2 in line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, annotate, multiple-axes

I've show the y1 label using plt.annotate, but I couldn't do the same for the y2. Could you help me?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))

x = [201901, 202001, 202101, 202202]
y1 = [6.86, 21.45, 6.25, 0.88]
y2 = [6.33, 6.33, 7.04, 5.63]

plt.box(False)
plt.plot(x, y1, marker='o', label='Your Return')
plt.plot(x, y2, marker='o', label='Benckmark')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Your Return vs Benckmark', pad=30)
plt.xlabel('Period')
plt.ylabel('Return')

for x, y in zip(x, y1):
    label = y
    plt.annotate(label, (x, y),
             xycoords="data",
             textcoords="offset points",
             xytext=(0, 10), ha="center")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to add another for loop for `y1` to annotate the data. I've also renamed `x` to `x_` as the name of the iterator otherwise it overrides your original variable.

```
for x_, y in zip(x, y1):
    label = y
    plt.annotate(label, (x_, y),
             xycoords="data",
             textcoords="offset points",
             xytext=(0, 10), ha="center", color ='blue')


for x_, y in zip(x, y2):
    label = y
    plt.annotate(label, (x_, y),
             xycoords="data",
             textcoords="offset points",
             xytext=(0, -10), ha="center", color= 'orange')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Suraj Shourie. It works very well!